# Override MetaData UIHint in Derived Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

EF creates  the Item class, I then create a partial Item class with a metadataType, ItemMD.

In certain cases, I want to use the UIHint defined in ItemMD, but in others, I want to override the UIHint to use another editor. So I try creating a derived class that inherits ItemMD....but I don't think this is how you are supposed to do it. It compiles, but I get inconsistent behaviour....when I have 5 fields in my Razor form, 4 are using the base ItemMD UIHint and 1 is using the derived class UIHint. Not sure why the inconsistency.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ItemMD))]
public partial class Item : AuditStamps, IEntity, IAuditStamps
{
}

public partial class ItemMD
{
public int Id { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Company Id")]
public int CompanyId { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Short Description")]
public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Type")]
[UIHint("ItemAtrributesComboBox")]
public virtual string Attribute1 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Color")]
[UIHint("ItemAtrributesComboBox")]
public virtual string Attribute2 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Finish")]
[UIHint("ItemAtrributesComboBox")]
public virtual string Attribute3 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Texture")]
[UIHint("ItemAtrributesComboBox")]
public virtual string Attribute4 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Gauge")]
[UIHint("ItemAtrributesComboBox")]
public virtual string Attribute5 { get; set; }

public class ItemSearchFiltersViewModel : OTIS.domain.InventoryMgmt.Item.ItemMD
{
    [Display(Name = "Type:")]
    [UIHint("ItemAttributesDDL")]
    public override string Attribute1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Color:")]
    [UIHint("ItemAttributesDDL")]
    public override string Attribute2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Finish:")]
    [UIHint("ItemAttributesDDL")]
    public override string Attribute3 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Texture:")]
    [UIHint("ItemAttributesDDL")]
    public override string Attribute4 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Gauge:")]
    [UIHint("ItemAttributesDDL")]
    public override string Attribute5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Should Item have the attribute `[MetadataType(typeof(ItemSearchFiltersViewModel))]`?

Comment: I don't think so. In 99% of the cases, I want Item to use ItemMD metadata...don't know if there is a way to override which metadatatype that is being used. I tried by creating a derived class of ItemMD

Comment: But I believe with your current `MetadataType` attribute, you're ignoring the derived class's tags in favor of ItemMD's.

Comment: I'm using ItemSearchFiltersViewModel in my view, not Item...so I was thinking it should be using that, which overrides ItemMD...Item and it's metadatatype doesn't even come into play.

Comment: You could be right, I am not an expert in this area.